# KivyMD RecycleView has low FPS & lags

Tags: kivy, kivy-language, python-3.8, kivymd

I am using Python 3.8.12, Kivy 2.0.0 & KivyMD-0.104.2
I am running my app on PyCharm on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a ASUS ROG STRIX GL503VD.
My issue is that every time i use a for loop to generate content in KivyMD BottomNavgation using RecycleView, no matter what content (might be even a for i in range(100)), the app is starting to move very slow (when manually resizing it takes around 10 seconds to resize correctly). Also i have FPS under 50 on the tab in which i generated the data while in the empty ones i get @80 FPS.
The issue doesn't seem to happen when i run lets say for i in range(100) in Kivy 2.0.0, but i would prefer to stick to KivyMD.

I've been looking in the last week on the internet for solutions but no luck and is a bit hard to understand kivy documentation regarding RecycleView.

Below is my code, please correct me if i did something out of "good practice". I just started to learn Kivy and i'm a beginner in Python (@1 year).

Thank you very much.

**EDIT**: Also when deployed to Android it works below 30 FPS on a Xiaomi Redmi Note8 Pro.

**main.py**

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp as md
from kivymd.uix.list import TwoLineListItem

import json as js
#from kivy.utils import platform
from kivy.core.window import Window

'''
if platform == "android":
    try:
        from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
        request_permissions([Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])
    except:
        pass
'''

class MainApp(md):
    def build(self):
        Window.size = (491, 1064)
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Red'
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = '50'
        layouts = Builder.load_file("layouts.kv")
        return layouts
    def on_start(self):
        for key, value in self.read_list().items():
            self.root.ids.container1.add_widget(TwoLineListItem(text=f"{key}", secondary_text="Tests : {}".format(len(value))))
        self.fps_monitor_start()
    def read_list(self):
        with open('tests.json', 'r') as read_test:
            #82 lines in test_list dict
            test_list = js.load(read_test)
        return test_list


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

**layouts.kv**

```
<MainLayout>
#:import get_color_from_hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
MDGridLayout:
    cols: 3
    size_hint: 1, 1
    MDBottomNavigation:
        panel_color: get_color_from_hex("#008080")
        text_color_active: get_color_from_hex("#FFFFFF")
        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: 'Item1'
            text: 'item_1'
            icon: 'language-python'
            MDGridLayout:
                cols: 1
                RecycleView:
                    MDList:
                        id: container1

        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: 'Item2'
            text: 'item_2'
            icon: 'language-cpp'
            MDBoxLayout:
                RecycleView:
                    MDList:
                        id: container2


        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: 'Item3'
            text: 'item_3'
            icon: 'language-javascript'
            MDBoxLayout:
                RecycleView:
                    MDList:
                        id: container3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not actually using the `RecycleView`. To use a `RecycleView`, you must have a `RecycleLayout` as its child, a `viewclass`, and a `data` list that indicates the items in the `RecycleLayout`.

Here is one way to use the `RecycleView` in your `App`. First, modify the `kv` to indicate the `RecycleLayout` and the `viewclass`:

```
MDGridLayout:
    cols: 3
    size_hint: 1, 1
    MDBottomNavigation:
        panel_color: get_color_from_hex("#008080")
        text_color_active: get_color_from_hex("#FFFFFF")
        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: 'Item1'
            text: 'item_1'
            icon: 'language-python'
            MDGridLayout:
                cols: 1
                RecycleView:
                    id: container1
                    viewclass: 'TwoLineListItem'
                    RecycleBoxLayout:
                        default_size: None, dp(75)
                        default_size_hint: 1, None
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: self.minimum_height
                        orientation: 'vertical'
```

The above moves the `container1` id to the `RecycleView` and adds the needed properties to allow the `RecycleView` to operate.

Then the `on_start()` method can be modified to create the `data` list for the `RecycleView`:

```
def on_start(self):
    data = []
    for key, value in self.read_list().items():
        data.append({'text': f"{key}", 'secondary_text': "Tests : {}".format(len(value))})
    self.root.ids.container1.data = data
    self.fps_monitor_start()
```

Comment: Works like a charm !
Now FPS is stable and there's little to no lag while resizing.
Thank you so much !!!